# Sofa recliner difficult to lock in place

Tags: furniture

I have Lane Sofa recliner that lets up and down ok, but it is difficult to get it lock in place. I have greased it down underneath and a quick glance of under there doesn’t seem to show where any adjustments can be made? This is an older sofa.Any suggestions?
[image: pic1]
[image: pic2]
[image: pic3]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because furniture operation/repair isn't home improvement.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because furniture operation/repair isn't home improvement

Answer (score 0):

Recliner mechanisms definitely wear out.  I have never heard of adjustments.  If everything is still bolted down properly and nothing is loose it may be time for a replacement.  I talked to a furniture man once.  He said that there is little you could do with them when they start to go.